# Getting OS name from Failover cluster manager console

Tags: powershell, python, windows-server-2016

Below is screenshot of Windows 2016 Failover Cluster Manager console.

[image]

You can see **Operating System** field at down right corner.

Is there any way to get this info programmatically ?

**Powershell** is preferred.

Answer (score 0):

#### Is there any way to get this info programmatically ?

> Powershell is preferred.

Use the following command:

```
(Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem).caption
```

Example:

```
> (Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem).caption
Microsoft Windows 7 Home Premium
>
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [PowerShell commands - PowerShell - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/ps/)
- [Get-WmiObject - PowerShell - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/ps/get-wmiobject.html)